# Symfony2: Error with forms when I send it twice

Tags: php, forms, symfony, request

I have a form made with Symfony 2.4, the code is:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new Profile(), $usuario);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isValid()) { 
        echo "Valid";
}
```

The first time I send this form, all is right and I see "Valid" printed.
If I send again this form, my browser said me the page is not redirecting properly and I can't refresh. The solution is remove cookies (session) and enter again.

If I remove:
   $form->handleRequest($request); and $form->valid ...
Works "fine", so I can send the form several times, but obviusly isn't correct.

Somebody can help me!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use redirect if form is valid:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new Profile(), $usuario);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ( $request->isMethod('POST') ) {
    if ($form->isValid()) { 
        echo "Valid";
        // Handle form data
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home')); // redirect to any route
    } else {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home')); // redirect to any route
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have the same problem, in my code I have a redirect but the second time I send the form the problem is the same.

Comment: Use check for requested method first. Check for update, please

Comment: Thanks ;) I have fixed this and also I had another mistake with encoder, but now it's solved. Thanks again.